# Set relationship between custom_post_types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create and enforce such a  relationship between custom_post_types. 
[image: parent_chlid]

Question:
How to 'link' the post_types in a manner that allows finding parent/child of any post_type?

Examples:
Querying for parent of 'barter' should give `classified_post_type` .
Querying for leaf nodes of user_post_type gives all the leaf nodes. etc

I understand this cannot be achieved just by creating custom_post_types. But is there any way like taxonomy/metafield to link different custom post types together ? Actually I am not bent on using customn_post_types. Just want the above mentioned behaviour, if possible.

ty

Comment: If you want a quick solution, the [Posts 2 Posts plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) is easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you create a common hierarchical taxonomy that you register with each of your custom post types.

The terms of this taxonomy would match your custom post types (for example use the custom post type slug as the term slug).

You can then structure your taxonomy to match your designed hierarchy, and every time you need to find the parent/child you refer back to the taxonomy.

You could have a parent_post and a child_post meta fields to store the post IDs of the respective parent and child post.

Answer (score 2):

use taxonomy then you can identify by category (like post category or tags).

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_tax' );


function create_custom_tax() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'category',
        'user-post-type',  // name of your custom post type
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ), 

            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? Link only answers get deleted and cleaned up. Thanks.

Comment: Example add dear. please check and let me know if you have again any issues.

Thanks for reply. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Milo said, a quick solution would be Posts 2 Posts plugin. I've been using [Pods Framework](https://www.pods.io) for this for about 2-3 years now. It's easy implement relationships using it's UI interface or via it's powerful API.